# zsh kill Ctrl + Backspace, Ctrl + Delete

Tags: zsh, line-editor

How to configure zsh such that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> kills the word before point? How to achieve that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> kills the word after point?

I use urxvt as terminal emulator.

Comment: Firstly, you should define "word".  Is it only alphabetic characters?  All non-space characters?

Comment: word like it is used in emacs terminology

Comment: If none of the solutions below work refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252419/in-zsh-how-do-you-bind-ctrlbackspace-to-delete-the-previous-word.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'll focus on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> first.

The zsh command to delete a whole word forwards is called `kill-word`.  By default it is bound to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

How to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> do it too depends on which terminal emulator you are using.

On my system, this works in xterm and Gnome Terminal:

```
bindkey -M emacs '^[[3;5~' kill-word
```

and for urxvt, you should do:

```
bindkey -M emacs '^[[3^' kill-word
```

If that doesn't work, try typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> to see what the value is on your system.

You could even add both of those together to your `.zshrc`, or use the output of `tput kDC5` instead of hard-coding the sequence.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> seems harder.

On my system, pressing that is the same as pressing just <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

If yours is the same, I think your best option is to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> instead.

Comment: I use urxvt as terminal emulator

Comment: `Ctrl + Backspace` doesn't work

Comment: You need `^[[3^` for urxvt.  `Ctrl+V` `Ctrl+Delete` would show you this.

Comment: Thanks, I have added bindkey `'^[[3^' kill-word
bindkey` and  `'^H' backward-kill-word` to my .zshrc. Now it works!

Comment: @user5289: Ah, sorry, we misunderstood each other.  I don't think `^H` or `^?` will work for `Ctrl+Backspace`.  In fact it seems such a binding is not possible.  `Alt+Backspace` or `Ctrl+W` might be adequate replacements.

Answer (score 23):

Add the following to your `~/.zshrc`

```
bindkey '^H' backward-kill-word
bindkey '5~' kill-word
```

Comment: I'm using xfce-terminal and this works but not the accepted answer

Comment: Works for me on `gnome-terminal`

Comment: Can confirm that this works on `kitty` too

Comment: Works on git bash / `mingw`

Answer (score 8):

On urxvt, for the deleting backwards part, I simply have in my `.zshrc` the following:

```
bindkey '^H' backward-kill-word
```

and it allows me to delete the previous word with ctrl+backspace

Answer (score 2):

I've got this in my `.Xresources`:

```
URxvt.keysym.C-BackSpace:       \033[33~
```

and that in my `.zshrc`:

```
bindkey -M main -M viins -M vicmd   '^[[33~'    backward-kill-word
```

This kills each whitespace seperated word. Note that '^[' is the Escape character. You have to `xrdb -load .Xresources`, open a terminal and then hit `^V` followed by `^BackSpace`.

Answer (score 1):

Type `showkey -a` in your `zsh`, and enter the key combination(s) that you want (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd>). I'm also using `zsh` and for me:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> is `^H`

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> is `^[[3;5~`

Then in your `.zshrc` file, add these lines:

```
# Ctrl+Backspace: kill the word backward
bindkey -M emacs '^H' backward-kill-word
bindkey -M viins '^H' backward-kill-word
bindkey -M vicmd '^H' backward-kill-word

# Ctrl+Delete: kill the word forward
bindkey -M emacs '^[[3;5~' kill-word
bindkey -M viins '^[[3;5~' kill-word
bindkey -M vicmd '^[[3;5~' kill-word
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact the output of `showkey -a` on my Kali is:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> is `^?`
- <kbd>Backspace</kbd> is `^H`

So the accepted answers here just made my <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to delete words.

For anyone that happens to have the same behavior, add in your `~/.zshrc` file this line:

```
bindkey '^?' backward-kill-word
```